# XmlSerialization throwing error when deserializing?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, serialization

I am trying to serialize an object into the database using xml serialization, however when deserializing it I am getting an error.

The error is ***There is an error in XML document (2, 2)*** with an inner exception of `"<MyCustomClass xmlns=''> was not expected."`

The code I am using to serialize is:

```
public static string SerializeToXml<T>(T obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return string.Empty;

    StringWriter xmlWriter = new StringWriter();
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj);
    return xmlWriter.ToString();
}

public static T DeserializeFromXml<T>(string xml)
{
    if (xml == string.Empty)
        return default(T);

    T obj;
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    StringReader xmlReader = new StringReader(xml);
    obj = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
    return obj;
}
```

The SerializedXml begins with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MyCustomClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

This is my first time using serialization and I'm wondering what I'm doing something wrong with my code.

Comment: As an aside, normally `xmlReader` and `xmlWriter` would be used for instances of `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter`, not `StringReader` and `StringWriter`.

Comment: To solve this, I think we'll need to see the declaration of `MyCustomClass`, as well as the rest of the XML.

Comment: It is telling me I can't create an instance of the abstract class XmlWriter

Comment: My equivalent code works good. Can you serialize empty class? Then add some properties to it.

Comment: The MyCustomClass code is fairly long... it contains no attributes other then `[Serializable]` and its only property is a CustomObservableCollection (inherited from base ObservableCollection) of CustomObjects.

Comment: @Rachel: please don't put tags like "C#" in your title. It's enough to have them in your tags.

Comment: Would I be correct in thinking your XML does't actually say
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>
 but rather 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>

since the quotes aren't supposed to be escaped like that in the XML but if you copied it out of a debugger window it would be.

If so will you or someone edit it for clarity?

Comment: Yes you are correct, I copied that from the debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, I just realized my problem was stupidity =/

I was serializing the class but trying to deserialize the ObservableCollection only. Once I changed that to serializing/deserialing the correct object it works great, although I thank you for the tip about `using` blocks

Answer (score 1):

BTW, you need `using` blocks around your code:

```
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    obj = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, XmlSerialization exceptions is a piece of crap.

You normally have to drill down into countless levels of inner exceptions to get to the real error.

Comment: I will keep that in mind when doing any other debugging, Thanks